# why inline styling &:hover will not have any effect in react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to add `hover effect` to a `span element` as shown below.

- Hover effect doesn't work when added inside
  style prop.
- But, If it is written in separate css file it will work

**I just want to know, Why it is So?**

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-resonance-stqbf9?file=/src/App.js

**App.js**

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span
        style={{
          fontSize: "4em",
          color: "blue",
          "&:hover": {
            color: "green"
          }
        }}
      >
        Element
      </span>
      <div></div>
      <span className="ele">Element 2</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**styles.css**

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.ele {
  font-size: 4em;
  color: blue;
}

.ele:hover {
  font-size: 6em;
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: you can't write hover in inline css

Comment: @iamhuynq If so! you can give one simple example

Comment: Material UI example https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-cloud-9py6me?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

That because we can't specify the inline styles for pseudo elements and pseudo classes. You can use it with the,

1. Internal - by using a `<style>` element in the  section.

An internal CSS is defined in the  section of an HTML page, within a  element.[example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_css_internal)

2. External - by using a  element to link to an external CSS file
   To use an external style sheet, add a link to it in the  section of each HTML page.[example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_css_external)

Comment: Examples are very good way to understand things better!

Comment: @VikasAcharya I added some explanation with some examples with the my answer

Comment: What you are trying to convey I'm not getting. none of your example showcase hover effect. Read my question again and u can use the link I provided to do some code.

Comment: @VikasAcharya simply the answer for your question is: you can't add hover like pseudo elements or pseudo classes for inline styles. hover is pseudo element. That's why I told you that  we can't specify the inline styles for pseudo elements and pseudo classes

Comment: point 1 and 2 is unnecessary

Comment: @VikasAcharya I added those examples with points, since you asked me to add some explanation with examples.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [JSS Plugin](https://cssinjs.org/?v=v10.9.1-alpha.2) which supports the psudo-selectors inline style, or you should use Material UI, which also support this plugin.

Comment: Can u give a simple example of material UI